# Access Key Not working In IE for click

Tags: javascript, html

I need to override the default functionality of setting the focus on html object to click it. I have a drop down menu which opens on `onclick` or `onmouseover` event. In that menu I have a signOff tab which needs to be fired from access-keys ("G") in my case. This is happening fine in chrome and mozilla but not in IE because IE sets the focus on element on pressing access key by default.

```
<div class="inD">
    <ul>
        <li class="user" onclick="showMenu(this, true, event)" onmouseover="showMenu(this, true, event)" onmouseout="hideMenu(this, true, false, event)" role="presentation">
            <label class="LBLmenustd">Default Admin User2</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="listPop">
         <li>.... </li>                        
         <li>.... </li>
        <li>.... </li>                       
        <li class="pD" onclick="doAction('SignOff',event);hideMenu(this, true, true, event);" role="presentation" accesskey="G" 
            onkeydown="return handleMenuKeys(this, true, event);hideMenu(this, true, true, event);" tabindex="0" onmouseover="showMenu(this, true, event)" 
            onmouseout="hideMenu(this, true, false, event)">
            Sign Off
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Please suggest some method to override this functionality of setting focus to click directly in Internet Explorer.